# Strassen algorithm for matrix multiplication complexity analysis

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, divide-and-conquer, matrix

I see everywhere that the recursive equation for the complexity of [Strassen alg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) is:
$$T(n) = 7T(\tfrac{n}{2})+O(n^2).$$ This is not so clear to me.
The parameter $n$ is supposed to be the size of the input, but it seems that here it is one dimension of a matrix while the input size is actually $n^2$.
Also, each matrix of the input is divided to 4 sub matrices so it seems the recursive equation should be $$T(n) = 7T(\tfrac{n}{4}) + O(n).$$

Answer (score 13):

It's true that the parameter $n$ usually denotes the size of the input, but this is not always the case. For square matrix multiplication, $n$ denotes the number of rows (or columns). For graphs, $n$ often denotes the number of vertices, and $m$ the number of edges. For algorithms on Boolean functions, $n$ denotes the number of inputs, though the truth table itself has size $2^n$. There are many other examples.

Answer (score 5):

It's back to the size of the matrix. Suppose the original matrix is $n\times n$. Hence we will consider $T(n)$ as a computation of two matrix with size of $n\times n$. When we divide the original matrix to 4 part, size of each part is $\frac{n}{2}\times \frac{n}{2}$. Hence, the computation cost of multiplication of two matrices with this size is $T(\frac{n}{2})$.

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity is *often* based on the input size, but it is not an absolute requirement. In this case, for the multiplication of n x n matrices, it seems most natural to count the number of operations based on n, not on the problem size n x n.